# using .click() from code-behind

Tags: javascript, c#

How can I call .Click() Js function from C#?

```
HtmlElement[] x = new HtmlElement[50];
for (int i = 0; i<50; i++)
{
    x[i] = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")[i];
    if (x[i].InnerHtml == "verifica")
    {
        invokeScript(click(), x[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoting because of the clear lack of research as well as the lack of formatting.

Comment: Hello simone! Welcome to stackoverflow! You can't (directly) mix `C#` and `javaScript`... because one runs on a `server`, the other one on the `client`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`InvokeMember()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.invokemember(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
x.InvokeMember("Click");
```

This will simulate a Mouseclick similar to the `click()` method in JavaScript.

Comment: If you add some more info like a link to InvokeMember, I'll upvote